# Number Pattern Function in c++ using recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

Implement the following function using recursion. Do not use any local variables or loops.

void pattern(unsigned int n)

// Precondition: n > 0;

// Postcondition: The output consists of lines of integers. The first line

// is the number n. The next line is the number 2n. The next line is

// the number 4n, and so on until you reach a number that is larger than

// 4242. This list of numbers is then repeated backward until you get back

// to n.

/* Example output with n = 840:

840

1680

3360

6720

6720

3360

1680

840 */

//This is my code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void pattern(unsigned int n)
{
    if(n > 0)
    {
        cout << n << endl;
        return pattern(n * 2);
    }else if( n > 4242)
    {
        return pattern(n / 2);
    }
}

int main()
{
    pattern(840);
    return 0;
}
```

//My code just keeps doubling n, it doesn't divided back to the original n.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cpp
void pattern(unsigned int n)
{
    if (n > 0)
    {
        cout << n << endl;
        if (n < 4242)
            pattern(n * 2);
        cout << n << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `n < 4242` is not the opposite of `n > 4242`. Only `n <= 4242` is.

Comment: Thanks. Much Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The other two answers point out one of the issues (that `n > 0` is true whenever `n > 4242` is true), but the other issue is that you only call `pattern` with a `n / 2` if `n > 4242`. So you'll end up "ping-ponging" back and forth. For example, in the example output you showed in your question, when you hit `6720` you'd halve that to call `pattern(3360)`, but on the next call you'd then call pattern with `3360` doubled since `3360 < 4242`.

I think the most obvious way to do this is to split this into two functions and add a "direction" boolean indicating if you're going up or down:

```
void pattern(unsigned int n) {
   pattern_with_dir(n, true);
}

void patten_with_dir(unsigned int n, bool increase) {
    if (n <= 0) {
        return;
    }
    cout << n << endl;
    if (n > 4242) {
        pattern_with_dir(n, false);
    } else {
        if (increase) {
            pattern_with_dir(n * 2, true);
        } else {
            pattern_with_dir(n / 2, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Note you could also split this into 3 functions:

```
void pattern(unsigned int n) {
   pattern_up(n);
}

void pattern_up(unsigned int n) {
    cout << n << endl;
    if (n > 4242) {
        pattern_down(n);
    } else {
       pattern_up(n * 2);
    }
}

void pattern_down(unsigned int n) {
    if (n <= 0) {
        return;
    }
    cout << n << endl;
    pattern_down(n / 2);
}
```

But the most concise solution is to make use of the recursion stack to help you count back down:

```
void pattern(unsigned int n) {
   // Going up
   count << n << endl;
   if (n <= 4242) {
       pattern(n*2);
   }
   // this will be called "on the way back down"
   count << n << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated!

Comment: Sure. If the answer seems correct, please mark it as a correct answer.

Comment: you are using pattern_with_dir(n / 2, false); if you use recursion wisely, you don't need this at all.

Comment: @Nandu good point. Added two more options for solving this including the more concise single-function version.

Answer (score 0):

`if( n > 4242)` will only be evaluated if `(n > 0)` is not true. But whenever `n > 4242` is true, so will `n > 0` be.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It will never hit the else if, because then the first criteria (>0) is still true and it will end up in the first if statement.

Make the first criteria

```
if(n > 0 && n <= 4242) {
...
} else if(n > 4242){
...
}
```

Or invert the if and else if

```
if(n > 4242) {
    return pattern(n/2);
} else if (n >0) {
    return pattern(n*2);
}
```

Comment: In your first case, what happens if `n == 4242`?

Answer (score 0):

```
// ConsoleApplication3.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void pattern(unsigned int n)
{
    cout << n << endl;
    if (n > 4242) {
        cout << n << endl;
        return ;
    }

        pattern(n * 2);

    cout << n << endl;

    return ;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    pattern(840);
    return 0;
}
```